# Have flexdashboard knit to another file directory

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am working with the flexdashboard package in R. I would like to have the rmd file knit to another file directory - one that is different from where the RMD is stored.

I tried creating an R script that included the following:

```
rmarkdown::render(rmd.rmd, 
                  output_format = "html_document", output_dir = path)
```

However, this produced a normal html document- one that is not formatted as a flexdashboard. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this task?